# VB.net receiving a email

Tags: vb.net, email

i already know how to send a email using vb.net, however i cant figure out how to receive an email. I want to go into my email account and read a email and store it in a variable, is this possible? and if yes could any one give me some sample code, because that would be great.

just to get a good idea of what I'm using here's my code for sending a email,

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)        Handles Button1.Click
    Try
        Dim SmtpServer As New SmtpClient()
        Dim mail As New MailMessage()
        SmtpServer.Credentials = New  _
     Net.NetworkCredential("trowbridge97@gmail.com", "qwerty1205")
        SmtpServer.Port = 587
        SmtpServer.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"
        mail = New MailMessage()
        mail.From = New MailAddress("trowbridge97@gmail.com")
        mail.To.Add("trowbridge97@gmail.com")
        mail.Subject = "Alarm"
        mail.Body = "Some one is in your room"
        SmtpServer.Send(mail)
        MsgBox("mail send")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SMTP is used for *sending* email, not receiving it.

You need a POP3 or IMAP client. There are many commercial and free .NET libraries for both protocols.